# R crashes randomly

Tags: r

I have had `R 3.0.2` crashing at random times. I have reinstalled R again after uninstalling the same version.   I do not think is any of the packages as the crashes occur while working with different packages that prior worked fine. It happens when computing some functions/routines but it does not seem to be routine specific related.

```
Nombre del evento de problema:  APPCRASH
Nombre de la aplicación:            Rgui.exe
Versión de la aplicación:           3.2.63987.0
Marca de tiempo de la aplicación:   52430323
Nombre del módulo con errores:  R.dll
Versión del módulo con errores: 3.2.63987.0
Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores: 52430319
Código de excepción:                    c0000005
Desplazamiento de excepción:            0000000000022a9c
Versión del sistema operativo:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Id. de configuración regional:  3082
Información adicional 1:            d710
Información adicional 2:            d7107453bd4712fe75341007482db842
Información adicional 3:            3033
Información adicional 4:            303376387c0f552f51fb92acd44e3a83
```

When running by adding one computation (thus package) at a time the error does not occur. I have run a low memtest and found no problems. As well I run overnight while(TRUE){hist(runif(10000))} and it did crash

Comment: Are you using large data frames while working on it ?? Sometimes it happens while using large amounts of data.

Comment: Not really it worked fine until yesterday.

Comment: I don't think this question offers enough details to be answerable in current form. We cannot reproduce your setting, we don't know what you're doing. Can you provide any more details?

Comment: Memory errors? Leave it running `while(TRUE){hist(runif(10000))}` overnight and see if it crashes. Run a low-level memtest. And what is version 3.2 anyway?

Comment: I run a model that requires computations. It always crashes arbitrarely after the end of a computation and where has not yet started a new one. Packages differ for the computations. CPU and memory usage look fine. The errors occur in R.dll, an extension of an aplication.

Comment: It might still be an issue with an add-on package; memory errors can lead to memory corruption that doesn't trigger a crash until later (and apparently while some other package's functions are active)

Comment: When running by adding one computation (thus package) at a time the error does not occur. I have run a low memtest and found no problems. As well I run overnight while(TRUE){hist(runif(10000))} and it did crash